# Load user's registry, export data via batch file?

Tags: batch-file, regedit

I need to be able to, if possible, via a batch file to export a user's mapped drive.

What I was thinking was have it load their ntuser.dat file, export hkey_current_user\Network key and save it to a certain location.

Is that possible?

Here's the script to call their username, this will be done locally on the computer:

```
:: Call the User Name :::::
:start
echo.
SET /P EndUserUN=EndUserUN:
echo.
REGEDIT.EXE /L:C:\Users\%EndUserUN%\NTUSER.DAT
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, but unlikely to be the best or most appropriate method.

Comment: Why not simple `reg query "hkcu\network" /S>"%USERPROFILE%\MappedDrives.txt"`

Comment: Wouldn't that only work under the currently logged on person? I will not be logged on as that person when running this script. I just want an export of their mapped drives in .reg format.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a registry based script which should be `Run as administrator` and may perform the task for all of your users except for whoever you've logged in as:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "EK=Network"

Set "RK=HKLM"
Set "SK=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
Set "UI=S-1-5-21-"
Set "RV=ProfileImagePath"
Set "UH=NTUSER.DAT"
Set "TK=TmpHive"
Set "ER=HKU"

For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    '"Reg Query "%RK%\%SK%" /K /F "%UI%*" /S /V "%RV%" 2>Nul|FindStr /V "\.$""'
) Do (Reg Load "%ER%\%TK%" "%%~B\%UH%" 2>Nul
    Reg Export "%ER%\%TK%\%EK%" "%~dp0%%~nxB.reg" /Y 2>Nul
    Reg UnLoad "%ER%\%TK%" 2>Nul)
```

*It is absolutely untested!*

***Note***
Do not modify any line other than line `2`, (which is currently `Set` to the SubKey path you are hoping to save as a `.reg` file).